# Can i create a user with password for onedev running with docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a **docker-compose.yml** file with following.

```
    onedev:
        image: 1dev/server
        volumes:
            - ./volumes/onedev_data:/opt/onedev
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:6610:6610
            - 127.0.0.1:6611:6611
```

I am wondering if there is a way to have it start with or create a user with password for onedev without having to create one myself by visiting http://localhost:6610 to create one?

Alternative like running a bash script when onedev docker is up to create a user with password for onedev docker my work for what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, can you using bash script for create user and password
`!#/bin/bash useradd -m -p PasswordHere test`

Comment: "useradd" if i remeber is for create a use in linux.
What is want is to create a user with password in the docker with image of onedev that can be used to log in onedev site.

Comment: send the tutorial that's you're using for install onedev here or inbox